# EKS aws-iam-authenticator usage

Tags: amazon-eks, aws-iam-authenticator

I have some questions regarding aws-iam-authenticator .

1. It comes with EKS by default, right?. If so, Can I install it in a existing EKS cluster?. BTW, I can currently login using configmap/aws-auth in the desired cluster. Are there any benefits?
2. When should I use aws-iam-authenticator ?

Thank you!!

I need to clarify what aws-iam-authenticator is used for.